# How To use ngforage in angular 10

Tags: angular, npm

I have upgraded my app from angular 9 to angular 10
I have followed this step for adding ngforge
For Angular versions >=9.0.0 and ngforage versions >=6.0.0 you can use Angular CLI:
**ng add ngforage**
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngforage
ngforgeconfig.ts file is generated Now I Have No idea how to use it

Answer (score 0):

I followed the documentation and added some functions. I hope this can help someone like me, that it would have been looking for information

> app.module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {DEFAULT_CONFIG, NgForageOptions, NgForageConfig, Driver} from 'ngforage';
  

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    // One way of configuring ngForage
    {
      provide: DEFAULT_CONFIG,
      useValue: {
        name: 'MyApp',
        driver: [ // defaults to indexedDB -> webSQL -> localStorage
          Driver.INDEXED_DB,
          Driver.LOCAL_STORAGE
        ]
      } as NgForageOptions
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule{
  // An alternative way of configuring ngforage
  public constructor(ngfConfig: NgForageConfig) {
    ngfConfig.configure({
      name: 'MyApp',
      driver: [ // defaults to indexedDB -> webSQL -> localStorage
        Driver.INDEXED_DB,
        Driver.LOCAL_STORAGE
      ]
    });
  }
}
```

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForage, Driver, NgForageCache, CachedItem } from 'ngforage';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  providers: [NgForage, NgForageCache],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private readonly ngf: NgForage,
    private readonly cache: NgForageCache
  ) {}

  public getItem<T = any>(key: string): Promise<T> {
    return this.ngf.getItem<T>(key);
  }

  public getCachedItem<T = any>(key: string): Promise<T | null> {
    return this.cache.getCached<T>(key).then((r: CachedItem<T>) => {
      if (!r.hasData || r.expired) {
        return null;
      }

      return r.data;
    });
  }

  public setItem<T = any>(key: string, data: T): Promise<T> {
    return this.ngf.setItem<T>(key, data);
  }

  public removeItem<T = string>(key: string): Promise<void> {
    return this.ngf.removeItem(key);
  }

  public async ngOnInit() {
    this.ngf.name = 'SomeStore';
    this.cache.driver = Driver.INDEXED_DB;

    const obj = { id: 1, name: 'Lorem ipsum' };

    // Assign item
    await this.setItem('information', obj);

    // Get item
    const information = await this.getItem('information');
    console.log(information);

    //Remove item
    //await this.removeItem('information');

    // Get item to check value
    const resp = await this.getItem('information');
    console.log(resp);

  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hTDB.png)